# What is the single word that means ''how the body feels as it moves"

Tags: single-word-requests

I posted an earlier query seeking a single word that means how it feels in the mouth to form a word. It appears there is no such word yet, and so I am broadening my search. I am now therefore seeking that single word that references the sensory quality of the sensation of movement of ones body. Incorporating such things as the pleasure of stretching a muscle, the displeasure of moving awkwardly, the sensation when a body is flowing in dance.

Answer (score 5):

[Proprioception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprioception) is probably the closest you will come to the position-movement sensation in general use. It is from the Latin proprius, meaning "one's own", "individual" and perception, and

> is the sense of the relative position of neighboring parts of the body and strength of effort being employed in movement. It is provided by proprioceptors in skeletal striated muscles and in joints.

**Kinesthetic/kinesthesia** (kinesthetic sense) has been used inconsistently to refer either to proprioception alone or to the brain's integration of proprioceptive and vestibular inputs (which would be necessary in dance). The [vestibular system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibular_system), which contributes to *balance* and to the sense of *spatial orientation*, is the sensory system that provides the leading contribution about movement and sense of balance.

As to the pleasures experienced by these, I think something might be found in writing about yoga.